# Flutter Shared Preference in Text Widget

Tags: flutter

I have successfully saved SharedPreferences in my app but now i am trying to display the data in a Text Widget. This is my code

```
//profile details
  late String name;
  late SharedPreferences profileData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initial();
  }
  void initial() async {
    profileData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      name = profileData.getString('name')!;
    });
  }
```

Then in my text widget i have done this

```
                             Text('$name',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color:Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
```

And i am getting this error

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized.
```

what have i done wrong and how can i fix it

Comment: Try adding `await` before `profileData.getString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because setState() is only triggered after the build is completed, meaning that the `Text` widget gets built with an uninitialised `name`. For this purpose it would be best if you instead did either

Option A:

```
var name = '';
late SharedPreferences profileData;
```

Option B:

```
String? name;
late SharedPreferences profileData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initial();
  }
  void initial() async {
    profileData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      name = profileData.getString('name')!;
    });
  }
```

with

```
 Text(name ?? '',
       style: TextStyle(
       color:Colors.black,
       fontSize: 20.0,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     )),
```

Comment: option B worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I suspect here the problem is the initial build (the text value is a required parameter for a text field, which cannot be null). Try something like this:

```
Text(name ?? '',
  style: TextStyle(
  color:Colors.black,
  fontSize: 20.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  )),
```