# SharedPreference data in TextWidget

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

This is a login, that catch user data and write in the other pages, like his name, etc 
I set sharedPreference here:

```
Future<bool> login() async {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
SharedPreferences nome = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

var email = _emailController.text;
var senha = _senhaController.text;
var auth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$email:$senha'));
var url = Uri.parse("http://177.70.102.109:3005/autenticacao");

var resposta = await http.get(
  url,
  headers: (<String, String>{'authorization': auth}),
);

// List campos = [];

if (resposta.statusCode == 200) {
  await sharedPreferences.setString(
      'token', "Token ${jsonDecode(resposta.body)['token']}");
  await nome.setString(
      'nome', "${jsonDecode(resposta.body)['result'][0]['nome']}");

  print(nome);
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

}

And i want to receive and pass the 'nome' to a TextWidget in another class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Shared Preference in Text Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758275/flutter-shared-preference-in-text-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the other page you can write something like that:

```
class ExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExamplePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExamplePage> createState() => _ExamplePageState();
}

class _ExamplePageState extends State<ExamplePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    initNome();
    super.initState();
  }
  
  Future<void> initNome() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String _nome = sharedPreferences.getString("nome", "");

    _controller.text = _nome;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_controller.text)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that TextEditingController is not nessecary and not suggested for showing a value. Instead use a variable

Comment: How i can put a variable?

Comment: I already put as a var, but the text only shows when i click on screen

Comment: You can make string String nome global

Answer (score 0):

To read the value in some other widget you can use

> getString https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getString.html

Implementation would be similar to this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Text(sharedPreferences.getString("nome");
```

See this post for example:
[Flutter Shared Preference in Text Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758275/flutter-shared-preference-in-text-widget)